# Regex to disallow single quotes and braces in strings

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a regex that will Validate a input string and return true if it contains single quotes (') or curly braces { }.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[^'{}"]*$");

if (regex.IsMatch("a'a{ddd}"))
    throw new Exception("Invalid string.");
```

Can anyone please help with a regex?

Comment: Your regex is mostly correct. Just remove the double quote in the character class. The shown code does not compile due to this mistake. Maybe you mean a pattern like `@"^[^'{}""]*$"` but your intro sentence does not exclude double quotes. and maybe it's better to invert the regex to match a single expected letter: `@"['{}]"`. [DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6A9SQ7)

Comment: @SebastianSchumann its not working, it always come as true for both valid and invalid strings.

Comment: What input do you use? `Regex.IsMatch("a'a{ddd}", @"['{}]") == true` and `Regex.IsMatch("aaddd", @"['{}]") == false`. [DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BnGkxu) What do you expect?

Comment: The demo in my first comment constains a mistake. I didn't invert the regex. The written comment is correct.

Answer (score -1):

You wrote your regular expression correctly, but you forgot to escape the `"` character. Therefore, the syntax was not correct and the compiler doesn't know what to do. You can fix this by escaping the `"` inside the RegEx:

```cs
Regex regex = new Regex("^[^'{}\"]*$");

if (regex.IsMatch("a'a{ddd}"))
    throw new Exception("Invalid string.");
```